# where to config m2e lifecycle-mapping source directory and output directory?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, m2eclipse, lifecycle

m2e doesn't like my pom section: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration.

### Original POM

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFileExt>.xml</sourceFileExt>
                <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jasper</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

### Modified POM

After research in this forum, I changed it to :

```xml
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>                                     
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>

                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

However, where to specify the source directory and target directory? Everytime I compile, it didn't do anything for my jasper-report plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The error you had was due to m2e not knowing the jasper plugin, which is very common since m2e v1.00 is fairly recent so there are no connectors for most plugins. What i always do is I follow the suggestion in eclipse in the quickfix to ignore the error. If you do this, you'll see a comment in the new code saying that this change doesn't affect maven, it affects only m2e

Apart from that, leave your plugin configuration intact (what you have in the first code section) which i assume you tried and worked
In other words, the fix for the m2e error should not interfere with the actual configuration you set for the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Your version range in M2E configuration is wrong for that plugin, it should be:

```
<versionRange>[1.0-beta-2,)</versionRange>
```

This is the configuration of the plugin that works for me (my .jrxml files are in src/main/jasperreports):

```
<properties>
    <jasperreports.version>5.0.0</jasperreports.version>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jasper</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile-reports</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```